# Flutter - supabase_flutter 2.1.0 throwing an error on flutter run

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-flutter

I ran flutter pub get supabase_flutter and imported the package into main.dart and ran flutter run and it gave me this error. Anyone else experiencing this?

```
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/web_socket_channel-2.4.2/lib/src/web_helpers.dart:10:32: Error: The getter 'EventStreamProviders' isn't defined for the class 'WebSocket'.
 - 'WebSocket' is from 'package:web/src/dom/websockets.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/web-0.3.0/lib/src/dom/websockets.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'EventStreamProviders'.
  Stream<Event> get onOpenX => EventStreamProviders.openEvent.forTarget(this);
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/web_socket_channel-2.4.2/lib/src/web_helpers.dart:12:7: Error: The getter 'EventStreamProviders' isn't defined for the class 'WebSocket'.
 - 'WebSocket' is from 'package:web/src/dom/websockets.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/web-0.3.0/lib/src/dom/websockets.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'EventStreamProviders'.
      EventStreamProviders.messageEvent.forTarget(this);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/web_socket_channel-2.4.2/lib/src/web_helpers.dart:14:7: Error: The getter 'EventStreamProviders' isn't defined for the class 'WebSocket'.
 - 'WebSocket' is from 'package:web/src/dom/websockets.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/web-0.3.0/lib/src/dom/websockets.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'EventStreamProviders'.
      EventStreamProviders.closeEvent.forTarget(this);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/web_socket_channel-2.4.2/lib/src/web_helpers.dart:16:7: Error: The getter 'EventStreamProviders' isn't defined for the class 'WebSocket'.
 - 'WebSocket' is from 'package:web/src/dom/websockets.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/web-0.3.0/lib/src/dom/websockets.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'EventStreamProviders'.
      EventStreamProviders.errorEventSourceEvent.forTarget(this);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I expected the flutter application to run with supabase package imported.

Answer (score 1):

My English is not good, but I will answer.

I too spent a lot of time with the same problem.

The conclusion seems to be a problem with the recently updated version of web_socket_channel.

Modify pubspec.yaml as follows:

web_socket_channel: ^2.4.0 -> web_socket_channel: 2.4.0

Remove the ^ and force it to version 2.4.0.
If web_socket_channel does not exist in pubspec.yaml, add it.